# Beginner. Can someone teach me how to count the number of times the inner loop has been excecuted?

Tags: java

Can someone teach me how to count the number of times the inner loop has been executed?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab8Ex5{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int primeCount = 1;
        System.out.print(2);
        int num = 2;
        while (primeCount < 20){
            num++; // try next number
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int i = 2; i < num; i++){
                if(num%i==0) // divisible by i
                    isPrime = false; // not a prime
            }

            if (isPrime){
                primeCount++; // one more prime is found
                System.out.print(","+num);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

The number of counts should be 2415. I know that **int count = 0; for (...) count++ ;** could be used.
However, I don't know where should I put that on.

Comment: Do you want the count per iteration of the `while` loop or a total count?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a counter outside the loops.

Then you need to increment the counter inside the nested loop.

It will count the number of executions of the nested loop over the outer loop.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab8Ex5{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int primeCount = 1;
        System.out.print(2);
        int num = 2;
        int counter = 0;   // Define the counter and init it
        while (primeCount < 20){
            num++; // try next number
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int i = 2; i < num; i++){
                counter++;     // Increment the counter in the inner loop
                if(num%i==0) // divisible by i
                    isPrime = false; // not a prime
            }

            if (isPrime){
                primeCount++; // one more prime is found
                System.out.print(","+num);
            }
        }
        // Print the value of counter
        System.out.println("Done in " + counter + " steps");
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you know a number `num` is prime you don't need to continue, so you can add a check to the termination condition of your for-loop:

    for (int i = 2; **isPrime &&** i < num; i++){

Comment: @mmixLinus the code still work also if it is not optimezed not adding **isPrime &&** to the check in the for. I don't know if it is a first version of the code showing that the code can be improved or not, exactly counting the number of iterations and showing that they should not be all checked to answer in the negative case.

Comment: yes, I see it makes a good reason to count the unoptimized calculations so you can compare with optimized versions

Comment: thanks all. I think I can handle this after reading your comment. Thanks a lot.